# Symfony validate field if other field has specific value

Tags: symfony, assert

Code example:

```
$dataContent = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

$dataToCheck = [
            'name' => [
                new Assert\Required(),
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Type('string'),
                new Assert\Length(['min' => 4]),
            ],
            'nick' => [
                new Assert\Required(),
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Type('string'),
                new Assert\Length(['min' => 4]),
            ],
            'email' => [
                new Assert\Required(),
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Email(),
            ],
            'roleInCompany' => [
                new Assert\Required(),
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Type('string'),
                new Assert\Choice(['choices' => ['manager',''supervisor','team leader']]),
            ],
            'task' => [
                new Assert\Required(),
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Type('string'),
             ]

]

$constraint = new Assert\Collection($dataToCheck);
$violations = $validator->validate($dataContent, $constraint);
```

In above example I would like to validate 'task' only if 'roleInCompany' is set to 'supervisor'. In other case 'task' validation mast be skip.
I can't use entity class so I have to operate only on data like in example that I posted.

Please help me how to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: You are going to create a [custom validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html).

Answer (score 2):

In order to do something properly, I would advise you to use form Events of Symfony. Here is the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/form/events.html). You will manage to change dynamically your form depending on the result of another field.

In your case it would be interesting to use PRE_SET_DATA, it will allow you to modify a form depending on the pre-populated data (adding or removing fields dynamically).

And this is a exemple of your idea with Form Events

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('roleInCompany', ....)
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function(FormEvent $event) use($factory){
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $roleInCompany = $data['roleInCompany'];

           if($roleInCompany === 'supervisor'){
            $form->add('task', 'text', array(
            'required'=> true
            ))
           }

        }
        );
    }
```